# Looking for a secure and private web blog that I can use offline at times

Tags: privacy, security, offline

Is there any web blog that I can use privately and securely?  I would like to connect to my blog from any terminal and not risk losing it due to losing my computer.  As a bonus is there any web blog within this set that somehow provides a capability for offline use in case I am unable to get to internet access for a while?  Such a setup would be ideal for a world travel blogger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use use a little portable wiki like...
http://www.tiddlywiki.com/
...Which you can store/sync up with dropbox.

That way you can access it online and when you're offline, you can still access it and sync it back up to dropbox when you get the opportunity.

Comment: This might very well be the most useful tidbit of help I've ever received on any of the stackexchange websites.  That's saying a lot - I'm over 100 questions on stackoverflow.  I'm loving this!

Comment: Still loving TiddlyWiki a year later.